# Turn off default routing offered by VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

Is there a way in VirtualBox to turn off the default routing functionality offered and have one of the VMs act as a router. Below is how my setup looks like.

I want to make the OpenBSD (VMrouter) to switch packets between the two subnets. I'm doin this to get an understanding of how this all works basically.

Networking mode for all VMs : Internal Network

```
    ----VirtualBox-----
    |       |        |
  VM1    VMrouter   VM2
```

`VM1 -> CentOS 10.0.1.10/24`network
`VM2 -> BT5.0  10.0.2.10/24`network

`VMrouter ->`OpenBSD` acting as a gateway router with two VNICs one for each subnet.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this by using the `Internal Network` option available as an `Attached to:` option for the NIC.

[image: Image of the network adapter]

Give your VM1 a NIC in intnet1, give your VM2 a NIC in intnet2 and give your VMrouter a NIC in both of the intnets so it can route between the two.

Comment: Lain, thanks for the info. That is exactly how I'm having my setup though. I knew VirtualBox would route the packets between subnets. However, I would like to turn off that feature and make one of the VMs acts as an L3 router.